# The adjoint of a linear isometry on normed space is surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

I come across with the following question:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces over the same field and $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear isometry, with $\|Tx\|=\|x\| \, \forall x \in X$, then the adjoint operator, $T^* : Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ defined by $T^*(f) = f(Tx) \, \forall x \in X$ is surjective.

I would like to proceed as following:
As $T$ is bijective between $X$ and $T(X)$, we can define for each $g \in X^{*}$, $f = g \circ T^{-1} \in T(X)^*$ and extend such definition over $Y^*$.

Can I get a small hint from that?
Many thanks

Comment: Do you have any completness hypothesis on $X,Y$? Are they both Banach spaces?

Comment: Once you've extended $g\circ T^{-1}$ to an $F \in Y^{\ast}$, you're done, you have $T^{\ast}(F) = g$. Why can you extend $g\circ T^{-1}$?

Comment: Simly by Hahn Banach theorem. Did I go for the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Consider $g \circ T^{-1} \in T(X)^*$, which is bounded, as $T$ is an isometry. Hence, by Hahn-Banach, it can be extended to and $f \in Y^*$. We have 
$$ (T^*f)x = f(Tx) = (g \circ T^{-1})(Tx) = g(x) $$
for $x \in X$. Hence $T^*f = g$.